# AngularJS multi-step form (ui.router) submission

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, forms, angular-ui-router

I have multi-step AngularJs form that uses `ui.router`, see side below:

```
signup.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {

  $stateProvider

    // route to show our basic form (/form)
    .state('signup', {
        url: '/signup',
        templateUrl: './stepOne.ejs',
        controller: 'login'
    })

    // nested states 
    // each of these sections will have their own view
    .state('signup.form', {
        url: '/form',
        templateUrl: './stepTwo.ejs'

    })

    .state('signup.interests', {
        url: '/interests',
        templateUrl: './stepThree.ejs'
    })

     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/signup/form');
});
```

As you can that the form has multiple steps before it can be submitted. Each step has its own view.

Initially I only had a single page form and I was submitting the form to my API like so:

```
<form name="myForm" action="/signup" method="POST">
```

The above worked very well for a single page form **BUT** this does not work with a multi-step form.

**The reason** I believe is that when click on the submit button on the last step of my form the submit button does not have access to the user inputs in the previous form steps/pages. And the server/API requires all user inputs in the POST request hence it gets rejected.

So my question is how can I submit a AngularJS multi-step (ui.router) form using  `<form action="/signup" method="POST">`

**I have already tried** posting the form through a Angular $http POST function but that did not allow me to redirect the user on the server side using passport.js. You can see detail on that issue on my [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725074/http-post-passport-js-redirect/35725487#35725487)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you storing data for the form?

Comment: You could update the model and save it in localStorage or something and then retrieve it on submit. And then delete the storage :)

Comment: @SatejS do you mean storing on backend or front end before submission?

Comment: @Alok Thanks for comment. Is that a good approach security wise?

Comment: Front end before submission, reason i'm asking is because , is the form pushing data for each step, or so on and forth..

Comment: I have used it in the past and didn't come across any problems. Let me read a little more and get back to you.

Comment: @SatejS No the form is not pushing data for each step. It only seems to picking up the data on the last step/page of the signup form.

Comment: This might help [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router)

Comment: Exactly, the reason I was asking was because, the data from the earlier states was probably not being maintained somewhere!I had a similar issue, I created a global variable in my app.js that kept track of each step, and finally in the last step, you'd get the entire form data.

Comment: @SatejS Ive seen that link before and they are not using the `<form action="/signup" method="POST">`. I tried using their way but their way causes issue when I try to redirect the user server side using passport js. Please see the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: try putting form model on rootscope on statechange !! And then use the values from the rootscope on submit

Answer (score 0):

this logic is totally wrong, if you want go for multi step form in UI, you should not use routing, because one move to next form(next url), that old one will be removed from DOM, so you can't retain the already typed values.

In this case you can simply go with ng-if/ng-show/ng-hide method to move on next steps.

All the best...!!! vote if you like

Comment: @Kamal Raj I disagree, I think using routing is a good way to implement a multi-step form. It allows use to inject views in `ui-view`. See this link previously shared by Satej S https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router

Comment: this router mainly related compilation process, this will do parsing the entire html after getting ajax call. and then it will append, when you each time remove and update DOM, we can't retain the old one...

or otherwise if forcibly want to go with routing you have to write you directives like 'ui-routing'.

in this case you can also go with like below example:
https://jsfiddle.net/glenn_antoine/rNudn/